# MahApps TDD ShowProgressDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mahapps.metro

Sorry for two posts.

I have the following code which I stole from the MahApps example. This has the updated code example

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;

namespace MyNameSpace {
    public class MyClass {

    public MyClass(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator,IMyService myservice){
        _dialogCoordinator =dialogCoordinator;
        _mySerice =myservice;

    }
        public async Task<bool> MethodUnderTest() {
            var controller = await _dialogCoordinator.ShowProgressAsync(this,"Please wait...", "We are baking some cupcakes!");
            controller.SetIndeterminate();

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            controller.SetCancelable(true);

            if (!controller.IsCanceled) {
                controller.SetProgress(0.50);
                controller.SetMessage("Half way there");
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
                    _myservice.MyMethodIWannaTest();
                });

            }

            await controller.CloseAsync();

            if (controller.IsCanceled) {
                await dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this,"No cupcakes!", "You stopped baking!");
                return false;
            } else {
                await dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this,"Cupcakes!", "Your cupcakes are finished! Enjoy!");
                return true;
            }

        }

    private IDialogCoordinator _dialogCoordinator;
    private IMyService _myService;

    }

}
```

**How do I test to verify that MyMethodIWannaTest is called (Since I can't Moq ShowProgressAync???**

```
    using Moq;
    using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;

    [TestMethod]
            public void MethodUnderTestCallsMyServiceMyMethodIWannaTest() {
             var _mockDialogCoordinator = new Mock<IDialogCoordinator>();
            var _mockMyService = new Mock<IMyService>();


                // Arrange
                var viewModel = new MyClass(_mockDialogCoordinator.Object,_mockMyService.Object);

 //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO TO MAKE IT WORK?            
                _mockDialogCoordinator.Setup(
                   d => d.ShowProgressAsync(viewModel, "Please wait...", "We are creating your package!", true, null))
                   .Returns(Task.Factory.StartNew(Activator.CreateInstance<ProgressDialogController>)); //Still does not work always returns null :(

                // Act            
                viewModel.MethodUnderTest();

                // Assert
                _mockMyService.Verify(ms => ms.MyMethodIWannaTest());
            }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help appreciated!!

Comment: You are coupled to a class that you cannot mock. That should be a sign that the design may have a flaw and you are tying your code to things you do not control. You should wrap/abstract external parties behind interface and classes you do own and can mock. This will make your code more testable.

Comment: You are also mixing Front-end/UI and back-end concerns when you tie `MyClass` to the `IDialogCoordinator`. One way around this would be to use a mediator pattern or event aggregator to notify a service to display the progress dialog which would allow for a more loosely coupled and testable class